# How to auto merge Git branches prior to a Jenkins build?

Tags: jenkins

How to auto merge Git branches prior to a Jenkins build?

I have 2 builds, one for branch `master` and one for production.

I would like to do Git merge `origin/master` when I do the production build.

Comment: You could always use a build step that executes the needed git command as bash.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's supported by the latest Git Plugin on Jenkins. Just set `Checkout/merge to local branch` to `production` under the Advanced settings for Git in the Job configuration.

Then set the `Branches to build` to master, or just leave it blank to have Jenkins try and merge and build each other branch it finds to production.

It will do one `merge/build` for each branch. It can also push the merged branch back to the source it pulled from.

Check this out:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-AdvancedFeatures

Comment: how do you do this in a jenkins pipeline?

Comment: @red888 Never used pipelines.

Comment: @red888 did you figure out how to manage this in the scope of a Jenkinsfile? I'd like to implement this on a per-repo basis, but don't see how to do that since we're using the github plugin. So.. it's either change for all our builds, or for none. Yikes.

Comment: Is this going to take a clone of Master, merge the feature branch to it, then run the Jenkins build? If so, what happens to that temporary branch?

Comment: @Andrew use the `checkout` step and configure git plugin. I'd go as far as dropping any VCS repository specific plugins unless you require reporting build status. I'd love to do it via pure git command line, but that means storing private key on target machine where agent is running, instead of exposing it just for checkout step.

Answer (score 2):

You can do premerging via extensions block in pipelines (assuming you configured `checkout: [ $class: 'GIT_SCM' ]` already.)

```
[
        $class: "PreBuildMerge",
        options: [
            mergeTarget: "master",
            fastForwardMode: "FF",
            mergeRemote: "origin",
            mergeStrategy: "OURS"
        ]
]
```

Comment: In contrast to the accepted option, this works for me. I'm not sure if the plugin was updated causing a breaking change.

Answer (score 2):

I found at least on current Jenkins dragas' solution is almost correct. The merge strategy has to be **theirs** (or RECURSIVE_THEIRS since the plugin doesn't offer THEIRS) since the plugin checks out origin/master and merges the branch onto it, instead of merging origin/master onto the branch.

Also I found a bit of context missing. And the merge command needs email and username to be set:

```
checkout(
    [
        $class: 'GitSCM',
        extensions: [
            [
                $class: "PreBuildMerge",
                options: [
                    mergeTarget: "master",
                    fastForwardMode: "FF",
                    mergeRemote: "origin",
                    mergeStrategy: "RECURSIVE_THEIRS"
                ],
            ],
            [
                $class: 'UserIdentity',
                email: 'user@company.com',
                name: 'user123'
            ],
        ],
    ]
)
```

Comment: Intersting, I didn't know that checkout plugin has identity configuration for it. Guess you find out something new every day

Comment: @Dragas I only found this out when it failed and after researching how to set the identity here.