# How to configure the Jenkins advanced Git feature

Tags: git, jenkins

We are using Jenkins and Git. We are also using feature branches, but we were not taking advantage of the "advanced" features as documented on the Git plugin page (and described here: [How to auto merge git branches prior to a jenkins build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696653/how-to-auto-merge-git-branches-prior-to-a-jenkins-build))

My problem is that the documentation says that I can just enable this under "advanced" - but no merge option appears:

Jenkins project config page after expanding the "Advanced..." settings:
[image: Jenkins config]

We are running Jenkins 1.583 and [Git plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin) rev 2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Advanced view, you see "Add" button in your screenshot. There is a "Merge before build" option when you click on that "Add" button.

Comment: Thank you so much - that was were I expected it, but when I posted this question, it was not there. Today it is - not sure why it did not show up when I posted this - I was definitely looking for this...