# Cant push the code to git repository using the same credentials

Tags: github, jenkins, bitbucket

I have created a Jenkins job, which does the task of merging the Sprint code to master.
I have created a credential - say XXX (SSH with Private and Public key) and have specified all the details perfectly - Public key in BitBucket and private key in Jenkins

When I run the job, it does the following :

1. fetches the code into a workspace using the credentials created (XXX)   => Perfectly doing
2. merges (with --no-commit) the Sprint code into master   => Perfectly doing
3. Push the code to the master.  => Error

However at step 3, my job fails with the error :

```
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I fail to understand that if the code can be checked out / downloaded without any issues using the credentials XXX, why can't it push using the same credentials and throws an error?

Is this a genuine error or a misleading one?

Answer (score 0):

It's worth menthioning that target result can be gained by settings in pipeline / jenkins GUI ([see similiar SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696653/how-to-auto-merge-git-branches-prior-to-a-jenkins-build))

But in your case ability to clone (if we talk about not jenkins built in clone) is not automatically equals to push rights.

Please take a look on some settings:

1. try to push with `--verbose` flag
2. check which key do you use. Do you specify custom identity for this via flag?
3. check permissions for the key (in case it is added directly to repository)  /user and make sure you have write permissions.